# Настройка PHPSTORM

Tags: php, phpstorm, ide

открываю файл в пхпсторм чтобы к примеру внести некие правки и когда закрываешь файл, он автоматически сохраняет и перезаписывает под свои настройки, собственно вопрос, можно ли пхпсторм настроить так чтобы он не затрагивал ни кодировку ни так называемый стиль переноса строки (line separator), если еще точнее надо так, файл открыл, посмотрел, внес правки если надо и закрыл и чтобы сторм закрыл его с теми же настройками что и был ранее. Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Описанное Вами случалось только при некорректном выходе и перезапуске - например, без выхода из шторма с открытыми в работе файлами завершение работы компа, перезагрузка и прочее.

Поэтому - самый оптимальный вариант с двойной подстраховкой - корректный выход из шторма и подстраховка - закрытие файлов, с которыми  осуществлялась работа.

Если файлы закрыть и даже нештатно завершить работу, то проблем не будет - автоподгружать при перезапуске/запуске шторму нечего и "портить" тоже нечего.

Ну, а при желании могут выслать свои настройки - я давно им пользуюсь, хоть и не на полную мощь его, что там менял и как делал уже не помню в деталях - но настройки могу выслать.

[Скачать с диска](http://linktmp.com/6/jmo0vY2), ссылка до завтра

Comment: Спасибо, буду рад если если вышлете. Вам необходимо мое мыло?

Comment: Добавил в ответ (версия phpstorm 2019.1). Git убрал только.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду убрал git ?

Comment: Эти настройки экспортированы с моего рабочего storma - отключил при экспорте свои настройки git . У вас они будут ваши или по умолчанию.

Comment: Я не много не так вопрос прочитал, спасибо

Comment: ---> Пожалуйста)